# network drivers missing under boot camp xp on imac

Tags: windows-xp, internet, boot-camp, imac

I installed windows xp under boot camp on my early 2008 imac successfully, but none of the network adapter drivers got copied over.  (This wasn't a problem when I tried windows 7)

Does anyone know where I can get the drivers for either the wired or wireless internet adapters?  I wasn't even able to see the wireless as a device under xp oddly enough.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar trouble. I finally found some [Boot Camp update](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#boot%20camp) (3.1) which installed the wifi driver, allowing me to get the rest of the drivers.